# How to populate a Postgre column with random values

Tags: postgresql, random

This is one way you can generate random valued rows within  a postgre relation.

Answer (score 6):

Execute this query by replacing L, U and R:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
SELECT trunc(random() * U + L) 
FROM generate_series(1, R);
```

where,

- **L** - Minimum value
- **U** - Maximum value
- **R** - # of rows required

Comment: BTW max value = U+L-1